# Looping through Firebase Data generates empty table?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to loop through my Firebase database and put it all in an array. However, when I execute it, the array always comes up empty. How should I do this? Thanks.

```
categories = ["Appliances", "Arts & Crafts", "Beauty & Personal Care", "Books", "Clothing", "Electronics", "Home & Kitchen", "Movies & TV", "Sports & Outdoors", "Toys & Games", "Video Games", "Other"]

    for items in categories {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "items").child(items)

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for items in snapshot.children {

                let item = Item(snapshot: items as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.allItems.append(item)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is set up for this to work:

```
categories = ["Appliances", "Arts & Crafts", "Beauty & Personal Care", "Books", 

    "Clothing", "Electronics", "Home & Kitchen", "Movies & TV", "Sports & Outdoors", "Toys & Games", "Video Games", "Other"]

     for items in categories {

         let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "items")

         ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
             let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
                 for item in value.allKeys{
                     if let foundItem = value[item] as? String{
                         self.allItems.append(foundItem)
                     }
                 }
             }
             self.tableView.reloadData()
         })
    }
```

It also may help you if you declare your Firebase reference separately and then do `ref.child("items).observe`